# No modules found in custom Arch kernel

Tags: archlinux, cross-compilation, kernel

In order to test the patch linked to in the following post: https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/29#issuecomment-6884170 I need to compile a custom kernel for my Pi.

To do this, I followed the steps laid out here: http://elinux.org/RPi_Kernel_Compilation#Ubuntu_Linux

This all worked fine and I was able to boot my Pi, however now my wireless adapter has ceased to work (worked previously by adding ath9k and ath9k_htc to my rc.conf) and dmesg tells me: "Loading user specified modules: FAIL". Taking a look at lsmod I can see that no (?!) modules are loaded!

I think this has to do with the kernel not having the correct paths to the modules.

So my question is, how do I build a kernel with the above mentioned patch for Arch Linux on my Pi?

I'm currently building on Ubuntu, but I could setup a virtual x86 arch Linux if that would make things easier.

Comment: Did you edit .config to compile ath9k and ath9k_htc as a module?

Comment: Perhaps you didn't compile any modules? Did you run `make modules_install` when compiling the kernel?

Answer (score 2):

Turned out that all that was needed was to create a symlink to `/lib/modules/KERNEL_VERSION` in `/usr/lib/modules`.

Seems that Arch Linux likes to keep modules in this directory.

Comment: Ah of course, `modudules`… ;)